# Bootstrap menu on hover active link has not background

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Please, I am a little confused of this, I have a bootstrap menu with activated hover instead of clicking by this:

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
display: block;
}
```

**But when the hover menu is activated, the ACTIVE top link has no background, the ready example picture and link are here:**

[image]

([www.gardin.cz](http://www.gardin.cz))

**Can anyone help, please?? Thanks a lot!!**

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    background-color: #123456;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that only colours background submenu, not the active links at the navbar :(

Comment: Apply same procedure for other elements also. And please don't forget to accept the answer, it will be convenient to others.